# Como criar uma função que insira no fim da lista (PYTHON ) utilizando a assinatura : def insereFim(self, item)

Tags: python

```
class Noh:
    def __init__(self, campo):
        self.campo = campo
        self.prox = None

    def getCampo(self): return self.campo

    def getProx(self): return self.prox

    def setCampo(self, nc): self.campo = nc

    def setProx(self, np): self.prox = np

class LL:

    def __init__(self): self.inicio = None

    def taVazia(self): return self.inicio is None

    def insereInicio(self, item):
        temp = Noh(item)
        temp.setProx(self.inicio)
        self.inicio = temp

    def tamanho(self):
        atual = self.inicio
        cont = 0
        while atual is not None:
            cont = cont + 1
            atual = atual.getProx()
        return cont

    def busca(self, item):
        atual = self.inicio
        encontrado = False
        while atual is not None and not encontrado:
            if atual.getCampo() is item:
                encontrado = True
            else:
                atual = atual.getProx()

        return encontrado

    def imprime(self):
        atual = self.inicio
        elementos = []
        while atual is not None:
            elementos.append(atual.campo)
            atual = atual.getProx()
        print(elementos)

    def remove(self, item):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def insereFim(self, item):
    temp = Noh(item)
    if self.inicio is None:
        self.inicio = temp
        return
    fim = self.inicio
    while(fim.getProx()):
        fim = fim.getProx()
    fim.setProx(temp)
```

Comment: Você poderia adicionar à sua resposta **detalhes** sobre sua alteração para facilitar ao autor da pergunta o entendimento.